# How do I populate a nested field with array of ID to another collection using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two collections. User and Event. In my Event model, I have an object "attendees" with ("hosting", "pending", "accepted", "declined") that have an array of ObjectId's referencing the User. I am trying to grab a single event and have those populated with User information.

My Event Schema

```
const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        eventDate: {
          type: Date,
          required: true,
        },
        dateCreated: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
        dateUpdated: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
        },
        attendees: {
          hosting: [
            {
              type: Schema.ObjectId,
              ref: "User",
            },
          ],
          pending: [
            {
              type: Schema.ObjectId,
              ref: "User",
            },
          ],
          accepted: [
            {
              type: Schema.ObjectId,
              ref: "User",
            },
          ],
          declined: [
            {
              type: Schema.ObjectId,
              ref: "User",
            },
          ],
        },
```

My User Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      first: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      last: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, "Please add a valid email"],
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    pictureUrl: String,
    allergies: [String],
    preferences: [String],
    favoriteRecipes: [String],
    events: {
      hosting: [
        {
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: "Event",
        },
      ],
      pending: [
        {
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: "Event",
        },
      ],
      accepted: [
        {
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: "Event",
        },
      ],
      declined: [
        {
          type: Schema.ObjectId,
          ref: "Event",
        },
      ],
    },
```

I've looked through a ton of stack overflow and can't find something to help. Maybe I need to change my models? Here is my query:

```
db.Event.find({})
      .populate({
        path: "attendees.pending",
        model: "User",
      })
      .exec((err, docs) => {
        console.log(docs);
        process.exit(0);
      });
```

Comment: I advise to you change your approach and models,and why use `db` before the find?

Comment: const db = require("../models");

Then please "advise".